# Problems with parsing og:type seems unresolvable, please suggest a clear solution

Tags: facebook, parsing, graph, web

Dear fellow developers,

the past days I tried hard to have facebook understand my website what it is - a representation of a hotel/bed and breakfast - i am running with the help of OG. I completely failed. i read a lot here about people having problems parsing their sites as og:type "hotel" or "restaurant". i really tried to understand the situation but i can't help it with a strategy. I read different documentations on the OG site itself - but there is no clear approach - i found contradicting documentations on facebook, too. i tried to come up with a solution offering to implement the complete metatags like

```
<meta property="og:type" content="my_og_app:hotel">
```

buts still that just messed it up more.

At the moment I go with that which constantly have my site parsed as og:type:website where i want to go for "hotel" plus adding the geo-lacation as seen below:

```
<!-- Metatags for Viral Marketing / Open Graph / facebook.com  -->

<meta property="og:title" content="Bordemundo B&B - Grüner Urlaub in Patagonien"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="hotel"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bordemundo.com/patagonien-deutschland      /zimmer_ferienhaus_urlaub.html"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bordemundo.com/images/facebook_og_bordemundo.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bordemundo Bed & Breakfast Puerto Varas"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="340364045978919"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="Grüner Tourismus in Patagonien. Wildes Land, einsamer Strand, schöne Zimmer und organisches Essen."/>

<!-- Location -->
<meta property="og:latitude" content="-41.31513"/>
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-72.93576"/>
<meta property="og:street-address" content="km 3, Camino a Ensenada"/>
<meta property="og:locality" content="Puerto Varas"/>
<meta property="og:region" content="Los Lagos"/>
<meta property="og:postal-code" content="5550000"/>
<meta property="og:country-name" content="Chile"/>

<meta property="og:email" content="javiera@bordemundo.com"/>
<meta property="og:phone_number" content="650-123-4567"/>
<meta property="og:fax_number" content="+56-9-629-19443"/>
```

I appreciate any clear suggestions on that because none of the appearing posts help me. I understand that "hotel" is not supported by OG and more or less a facebook specific entity. but how am i able to make use of an appropriate code and method of implementation then?

i found a hint to declare and object type but in my app this need to be chained to an action. why? and what would that be good for?

saludos desde chile and thx for helping me out,

michael.

Answer (score 0):

Having troubles with the open graph, you should always use the [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Paste your url into the debugger and check the warnings and error messages it gives you:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Hey Lego, I did that from the beginning on. my site is: http://www.bordemundo.com/patagonien-deutschland/zimmer_ferienhaus_urlaub.html. it works BUT og:type is website and therefore the location data is not being accepted.

Comment: Try it without any type. You have a location. The docs say that the following metas are required for a location: *latitude, longitude, street-address, locality, region, postal-code, country-name* See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ under **Location**

Comment: Thx for sharing your thought, I am really glad? I will try, but what do you mean with "You have a location"? You mean, because I have this facebook page claimed already for Bordemundo?

Comment: Response Code: 206
Fetched URL: http://www.bordemundo.com/patagonien-deutschland/zimmer_ferienhaus_urlaub.html
Canonical URL: http://www.bordemundo.com/patagonien-deutschland/zimmer_ferienhaus_urlaub.html
Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property: og:type missing. og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Comment: Sorry, fellow helper. It didn't help. Above is the message being transmitted by the linter. it def. requests a type and wo it it still claims website as og:type. Any other ideas that could make it? I read anything available on Facebook and OG, but it seems a mysterium. Is there anyone out there having ever come to terms with that :-)?

Comment: i changed it back to give og:type:hotel. it now is ok with that and doesnt give an error. still it wont accept location data.

Comment: Seems like this type is incompatible with location meta. Ich würde vorschlagen bei 'Lage und Umgebung' *Location* zu wählen, bei 'Kontakt' *Contact Information* und bei dem Rest *Hotel*. Siehe auch hier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7656802/601466

Comment: Ahhh, das klingt gut. Aber meint das, hier herrscht eine semantische Ordnung der Inhalte. Wie erkennt denn Facebook, dass bei Lage und Umgebung die Location zulässig ist? Über Wort-Filter? Mann, wahrscheinlich ist das zu hoch für mich. Ich bin Hobby-Entwickler und scheinbar stoße ich beim Og an meine Grenzen.

Comment: Facebook erkennt nur das, was in den OG Metatags steht, also nur das was bei dem jeweiligen Seitenaufruf geladen wird. Bei jeder deiner Unterseiten müsstest du unterschiedliche Metatags setzen, wenn du meinen obigen Vorschlag umsetzen wollen würdest. Ist ne konzeptionelle Frage. Was willst du denn mit der Meta Info genau erreichen?

Comment: Also, das Problem ist folgendes, Lego: ich will einen Place für mein Bed and Breakfast, also etwas zum Check In. ICh habe alles gemacht, was dafür nötig ist, FB Page eingerichtet, die Seite geclaimed als Owner, entsprechend administriert. Nun habe ich das Problem, dass meine Seite als Place in der FB Search Bar auch erscheint und funktioniert. Aber eben nur in der Suche, nicht in der Statusortsangabe. Komisch ist, dass trotz allem selbst auf der FB-Seite der Stadt Puerto Varas das Business als Place aufgeführt wird. Nun dachte ich, dass ich, wenn ich meine Website mit FB verknüpfe und die Geo-

Comment: funktion nutze, FB davon überzeuge, das Business auch in der Suche als Place zuzulassen. Das Facebook-Team nämlich schweigt sich seit Wochen genüsslich aus, warum mein B. eben als Place gefunden, aber nicht als Place benutzbar ist. Ich bin so ziemlich am Ende mit meinem Latein. Viele beschweren sich zur Zeit über die schlechte Funktionalität des Mergings, aber Mergen ist ja wie gesgt nicht mein Problem - sondern das Check-Ins def. nicht möglich sind, obwohl die Page als Place geführt wird und auch findbar ist. Die FB Page heißt: Bordemundo B&B - Green Tourism in Puerto Varas. EIN MYSTERIUM!

Comment: Aha! OK! Ich glaube du musst den place mobil / per checkin anlegen, mit deinem Handy or whatever und dann als Page claimen. Steht alles hier: https://www.facebook.com/help/location/advertise Schau mal insbesondere unter **How do I claim a place for my business on Facebook?** Bin jetzt erstmal weg, schaue aber morgen wie weit du gekommen bist ; ]

Comment: Yo Lego,thx a lot for everything. Endlich geklappt, habe nen Kumpel gestern nen Check-In machen lassen, heute ohne Probleme en Platz mit meiner FB Page gemerged und sieh da, kann mich über den Status sogar vom Desktop loggen! Muchas gracias, facebook.com/bordemundo ist die adresse! du bist immer willkommen! grüße!

Comment: Freut mich dass es geklappt hat. Kannts gern meine Antwort als nützlich markieren ; ] Wenn ich mal nach Chile fliege, schau ich vielleicht vorbei : ] Suerte!

Comment: Bueno, danke Dir, Lego. Aber gerne doch, you`re welcome. Übrigens bin ich hier wieder am Ausgangsproblem, nach 3 Tagen fehlerfreiem Funktionieren, ist unsere Gruppe wieder zwar offiziell ein Place, aber taucht nicht als solcher in der Statuswahl auf. Ich habe es aufgegeben, zumal der Facebook Support schlichtweg gar nicht vorhanden ist, echt armselig von den Mädels und Jungs dort!