# Facebook like button on landing page in Google app engine (open graph tags)

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am using GAE as a landing page for my app (to be developed on GAE soon after)
I am trying to add social button (twitter, G+, facebook like)
It turns out for the FB like, I need to enter open graph tags in the html-head
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

To my surprise, my GAE templates are running in a  of an GAE-autogenerated html document.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=reciprocity-ring-001.appspot.com
So the FB like button tries to access the open graphs tags in the wrong html-head, i.e. it looks at the GAE-autogenerated head.

1/ How can I edit the GAE http-head

2/ How can I work around this issue without editing the above file?

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [scrapes Open Graph Urls for meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) (part of Open Graph protocol), so your [page content must be available via a simple HTTP GET](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8896773/opengraph-on-ajax-based-website), without javascript. Also, distinct Open Graph objects need to have distinct Urls. See how to handle this in one-page apps (such as GWT apps): [Facebook Open Graph Single Page Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725252/facebook-open-graph-single-page-apps)

With GWT you can have one-page app with distinct urls via url parameters: 
`reciprocity-ring-001.appspot.com`
`reciprocity-ring-001.appspot.com?object=1`
`reciprocity-ring-001.appspot.com?object=2`
You can also use Fragment Identifier (aka GWT history token): `reciprocity-ring-001.appspot.com#object2` This all point to same GWT app, parameters are just used to produce proper FM meta tags.

Then you must have a servlet (or jsp or other templating technology) that generates this host page with required FM meta tags. This must be done server-side so that FM meta tags are present even when page is requested via HTTP GET.

After this is done, you can place FB Like buttons in your GWT app, with appropriate `href` pointing to those Urls.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I am using godaddy with domain masking.
The domain masking create a frame in which my hidden domain opens.

At least I found that the information and framing is done at the godaddy level.
Not sure I can edit at will the html wrapper used for domain masking....