# Can we use two <meta property="og:type" content=""> in single page while using open graph for facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have two objects on the same page. and it giving error 
The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified:

Comment: Did you create the object using open graph into your facebook app settings? After that you should use the API Graphic explorer here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/ to test your action.

Comment: Yes I have created the objects using open graph, but I was just want to say that can we have two object in one page...

Comment: This ANSWER could helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656151/multiple-facebook-opengraph-objects-on-the-same-page/7659770#7659770